# cant get my div to scroll automatically with the content every time a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

Cant find any good solutions for this here on stack overflow. I have a div element that has content added to it dynamically. The div is already scrollable once a certain amount of content is entered into the div. What I'm trying to do is to get the div to scroll down automatically each time content is added so that the user does not have to scroll down manually to see the new content. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="messageContainer">
  <ul class="messageList"> 
    <li class="messageItem" ng-repeat="message in messages">
     Message:<input readonly class="messageText" ng-model="message.text" ng-change="messages.$save(message)"></input>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add angular-js tag to your question for more precision.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery.animate() everytime a new element is added.

```
$('.container').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".container div:last-child").offset().top;
});
```

Like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkehnkdk/4/

Answer (score 0):

Set `Element.scrollTop` to `Element.scrollHeight`. Like so:

In plain JavaScript:

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName ('messageContainer')[0];
var submit = document.getElementById ('submit');

submit.onclick = function () {
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
};
```

In jQuery:

```
var container = $('.messageContainer')[0];

$("#submit").click(function() {
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
});
```

The important part is setting `container.scrollTop` to `container.scrollTop`, if you're adding the content automatically every few seconds via an XMLHttpRequest, or whatever other method, just set `Element.scrollTop` to `Element.scrollHeight` after adding the content.